# How to search strings of one file in another file and print line number of the match in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have this 2 files:

file1

```
Ruby
C
Visual Basic
R
Objective-C
Basic
HTML
```

file2

```
5. ab cde fg Java hij kl
2. ab PHP dddf llf 
4. cde fg z o Objective-C oode
8. a12b cde JavaScript kdk
6. ab99r cde Visual Basic llso dkd
1. lkd dsk Ruby kksdk
3. Python dsdls
7. kdjd C jdjd
9. CSS dkdsk
7. kkd Basic jjs
3. rooor R kdk
```

I´d like to search the strings in file1 and if they are found within file2, then print the "the string of file1", followed by line number in file2,  and the line of file2 where each string is present.

The output format would be like this:

find "string" of file1|Line in file2 where "string" of file1 was found| text of line in file2 where "string" of file1 was found

For the sample file1 and file2  the output I´m looking for is:

```
Ruby|6|1. lkd dsk Ruby kksdk
C|8|7. kdjd C jdjd
Visual Basic|5|6. ab99r cde Visual Basic llso dkd
R|11|3. rooor R kdk
Objective-C|3|4. cde fg z o Objective-C oode
Basic|10|7. kkd Basic jjs
HTML|Not found
```

I've tried with the following code, but doesn´t find anything. My real file1 has about 32K lines and real file2 has about 48K lines.

```
require 'set'

f2_set = File.readlines("file2.txt").map(&:chomp).to_set
File.foreach("file1.txt") { |line| puts line if f2_set.include?(line) }
```

Thanks for any help

**UPDATE**

Below I show `file1` and `file2` proposed by @CarySwoveland and how would be the `output` for those inputs.

[image]

**UPDATE2**

Below samples of [file1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x7jsj5tdicz1nw0/f1?raw=1), [file2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hrv5p8j8r09himo/f2?raw=1) and output [file3](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vxkk8vs4s8khdma/f3?raw=1).

Comment: Depending on how other your need to do this operation it might make sense to build a hash with the language names as the keys and the line numbers as values. With such a hash each check would just be a simple lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume each line in file 1 appears in at most one line in file 2 and each line of file 2 contains no more than one language in file 1, which is consistent with the example given in the question.

Let's first construct the files. To make life more interesting, I've modified the contents of both files given in the question.

```
file1 =<<-END
Ruby
C
Visual Basic
C++
R
Objective-C++
Basic
HTML
END

FName1 = 'file1'
File.write(FName1, file1)
  #=> 51
```

```
file2 =<<-END
5. ab cde fg Java hij kl
2. ab PHP dddf llf 
4. cde fg z o Objective-C++ oode
8. a12b cde JavaScript kdk
6. ab99r cde Visual Basic llso dkd
1. lkd dsk Ruby kksdk
3. Python dsdls
7. kdjd C jdjd
9. CSS dkdsk
10. blah C++ blah
7. kkd Basic jjs
3. rooor R kdk
END

FName2 = 'file2'
File.write(FName2, file2)
  #=> 256
```

First read the lines of `FName1` into an array.

```
languages = File.readlines(FName1, chomp:true)
  #=> ["Ruby", "C", "Visual Basic", "C++",
  #    "R", "Objective-C++", "Basic", "HTML"]
```

Now, for convenience, order the elements of `languages` be decreasing length.

```
sorted_languages = languages.sort_by(&:length).reverse
  #=> ["Objective-C++", "Visual Basic", "Basic",
  #    "Ruby", "HTML", "C++", "C", "R"]
```

I've sorted the elements of `languages` by decreasing word length so that an attempt to match a line of `FName2` with 'Objective-C++' will be made before an attempt is made to match 'C++', and 'C++' will be considered before 'C'. Similarly, 'Visual Basic' will be considered as a match before 'Basic' is considered.

Next, create a hash whose keys are those lines in `FName1` that appear in a line of `FName2` and whose values are hashes identifying the line number and line in `FName2` for the given key.

```
language_to_file2 = File.foreach(FName2, chomp: true).
  with_index(1).
  with_object({}) do |(line,n),h|
    language = sorted_languages.find { |language| line.include?(language) }
    h[language] = { line: line, nbr: n } unless language.nil?
  end
  #=> {"Objective-C++"=>{:line=>"4. cde fg z o Objective-C++ oode", :nbr=>3},
  #    "Visual Basic" =>{:line=>"6. ab99r cde Visual Basic llso dkd", :nbr=>5},
  #    "Ruby"         =>{:line=>"1. lkd dsk Ruby kksdk", :nbr=>6},
  #    "C"            =>{:line=>"7. kdjd C jdjd", :nbr=>8},
  #    "C++"          =>{:line=>"10. blah C++ blah", :nbr=>10},
  #    "Basic"        =>{:line=>"7. kkd Basic jjs", :nbr=>11},
  #    "R"            =>{:line=>"3. rooor R kdk", :nbr=>12}}
```

We may now display the desired result.

```
languages.each do |language|
  print "#{language}|"
  if language_to_file2.key?(language)
    h = language_to_file2[language]
    puts "%d|%s" % [h[:nbr], h[:line]]
  else
    puts "Not found"
  end
end
Ruby|6|1. lkd dsk Ruby kksdk
C|8|7. kdjd C jdjd
Visual Basic|5|6. ab99r cde Visual Basic llso dkd
C++|10|10. blah C++ blah
R|12|3. rooor R kdk
Objective-C++|3|4. cde fg z o Objective-C++ oode
Basic|11|7. kkd Basic jjs
HTML|Not found
```

Comment: Surround the block of code that displays the result (`languages.each do |language| ... end`) with `File.open(<file name>, "w+") do |f|` and `end`, and replace the two `puts ...` statements with `f.puts ...`.

Comment: Hi Cary. Thanks. It works writing to an output file as you said. I have a question. your solution looks for a limited number of words? I ask because I tested with a more representative file1 and file2, as you can see below my UPDATE2, and in output only one text from file1 is found, even when the 5 sentences in file1 are present in file2.

Comment: Try changing `/\b#{Regexp.escape(language)}(?= |\z)/` to `/\b#{Regexp.escape(language)}/` and let me know.

Comment: Changing to the regex you suggested, this time only the second sentence was not found, this one `"The world's biggest cities: How do you measure them?"`

Comment: All five lines in the new file 1 (including `"The world's biggest..."`) were matched in file 2 after I changed `line.match?(/\b#{Regexp.escape(language)}/)` to `line.match?(Regexp.escape(language))`. Note `Regexp.escape(language)` is the same as `/#{Regexp.escape(language)}/`. My original regex was consistent with your example, where the strings in file 1 were followed by a space or were at the end of a line in file 2. That's not the case with the larger data set.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fix. It works now for the second samples. You're right, your first solution works for the first sample I posted. The real files have  file1 32K lines and file2 42K lines. I've tried your last code and  after 1:20 hours the code still running. I think could be normal due to the number of lines of real files.

Comment: To build the hash `language_to_file2` (42K keys) you need make up to 32K regex searches for each of the 42K lines of file 2. That's 1.344 billion operations, so it could take awhile. If you rerun it I suggest you include a counter and a `puts` statement that displays a line number and the elapsed time from start each time a new line in file 2 is processed. That would allow you to estimate how long the calculation will take. You might also try replacing `line.match?(Regexp.escape(language))` with  `line.include?(language)`. I'm guessing that would be considerably faster.

Comment: I edited my answer to replace `line.match?(Regexp.escape(language))` with `line.include?(language)`. I expect that will speed calculations.

Comment: Your last change really makes a big difference. Yesterday I needed to stop after 1:20 hours, now the execution time was 2 min!!! Thanks a lot for your great and kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem as it is stated does not have *a correct* solution because there is no way to explain Ruby that `Basic` (next to the last element in matchers list) *should not be taken into account* when matching the line `6.`. More sophisticated ruleset is required to accomplish what you want.

That would be a good starting point though:

```
matchers = File.readlines("file1.txt")
lines = File.readlines("file2.txt")

matchers.inject([]) do |acc, match|
  acc | lines.each.with_index(1).map do |line, idx|
    [match, idx, line].join("|") if line =~ /\b(#{match}\b)/
  end.compact
end
#⇒ ["Ruby|6|1. lkd dsk Ruby kksdk",
#   "C|3|4. cde fg z o Objective-C oode",
#   "C|8|7. kdjd C jdjd",
#   "Visual Basic|5|6. ab99r cde Visual Basic llso dkd",
#   "R|11|3. rooor R kdk",
#   "Objective-C|3|4. cde fg z o Objective-C oode",
#   "Basic|5|6. ab99r cde Visual Basic llso dkd",
#   "Basic|10|7. kkd Basic jjs"]
```

Comment: Thanks Aleksei. Your solution it outputs almost correct. I understand what you said about "Basic", but I'm not sure if there is a regex that could match C only when is alone (surrounded by spaces)?  I see that for "Basic" is more difficult.